# Define directory and search for string in each txt file and list files

Tags: python

I want to search for a string in a number of text files in a folder and its subfolders.

Then all files containing this string should be listed. How can this be made?

The string is just something like "Test". So no special chars. I thought of something like the following in a loop:

```
open('*', 'r').read().find('Test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple loop and the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module:

```
from glob import glob

for fname in glob('**/*', recursive=True):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        out = []
        if any('Test' in line for line in f):
            out.append(fname)

print(out)
```

If you just want to print:

```
for fname in glob('**/*', recursive=True):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        if any('Test' in line for line in f):
            print(fname)
```

Comment: Why is it not possible if I search in an xml file?

Comment: What is not possible? I suggest you open a new question with all the details (including a sample of your xml file)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking look at [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) with recursive set to true, consider following simple example

```
import glob
for fpath in glob.glob("**/*.txt",recursive=True):
    print(fpath)
```

it does print paths (relative to current working directory) of all `*.txt` files, including subdirectories (observe `**` in 1st argument)